# c beginner, vectors

Tags: c, vector

I'm a c beginner and i've a problem (as usual). I wrote this simple program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define SIZE 10

 main()
 {
    int vettore[9];
    int contatore1,contatore2;

    for(contatore1 = 0; contatore1 <= 9; ++contatore1)
    {
        vettore[contatore1] = contatore1*2;
    }

    printf("%d\n\n", vettore[9]);

    for(contatore2 = 0; contatore2 < 10; ++contatore2)
    {
        printf("%d\n", vettore[contatore2]);
    }

    printf("\n%d\n", vettore[9]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
18

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
9

10
```

Why the value of vettore[9] changes 3 times? And why it has the correct value only on the first line of the output? thank you :)

Comment: Btw, you should follow 1 style - `<Size` or `<=LastIndex`, using both is going to be confusing.

Comment: I would advise to use the name "array" rather than vector. Strictly speaking, vector is a correct term, but in C programming it more oftens refers either to mathematical vectors or the C++ type std::vector.

Comment: Also you should at least read [C bible](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0131103628/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=thgest-20&linkCode=as2&camp=217145&creative=399369&creativeASIN=0131103628) before asking basic questions here. No flaming, just for your own good.

Comment: Indeed.  The correct term in the C language is 'array'.  You should use this term to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `vettore` has 9 elements, but by referencing `vettore[9]`, you're actually referencing the *10th* element (since element indexing starts from 0).  So it's some random location on the stack, without a well-defined value.

The solution is to index only up to `vettore[8]`, or define `vettore` to have size 10.

Comment: ive just done a stupid question. I should read my manual with more attention before posting. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 5):

C arrays are zero based so valid indexes for a 9 element array are [0..8].  You are writing beyond the end of your array.  This has undefined results but is likely corrupting the next stack variable.

In more detail...  `vettore` has 9 elements, which can be accessed using `vettore[0]` ... `vettore[8]`.  The final iteration of your first loop writes to `vettore[9]`.  This accesses memory beyond the end of your array.  This results in undefined behaviour (i.e. the C standard does not specify expected outcome here) but it is likely that the address of `vettore[9]` is the same as the address of `contatore2`, meaning that the latter variable is written to.

You have a similar problem in the next loop which prints more elements than `vettore` contains.

You can fix this by changing your loops to

```
for(contatore1 = 0; contatore1 < 9; ++contatore1)
for(contatore2 = 0; contatore2 < 9; ++contatore2)
```

Note that it would be safer if you changed to calculating the size of the array instead, by using `sizeof(vettore)/sizeof(vettore[0])` in the exit test of your loops in place of hard-coding `9`.

Comment: Looks more like the address of `vettore[9]` is the same as the address of `contatore2`.  It accepts the first write and reads as 18, then during the second loop it reads as 9 as that is the value of `contatore2` at that point.  After the loop `contatore2` is 10 and thats what `vettore[9]` prints.

You should not rely not this behaviour though!!

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

```
for(contatore2 = 0; contatore2 < 10; ++contatore2)
{
    printf("%d\n", vettore[contatore2]);
}
```

you are displaying 11 elements of the vettore array (which is defined as a 9 ints array). I think that the error is in the random allocation on the stack

Answer (score 0):

the `vettore` size as you defined is `9`

```
int vettore[9];
```

and in your loop you start from `0` till `9` so you are playing with `10` elements of the array and  not `9` (size of the array)

you should define the array with size `10`

```
int vettore[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays (i.e. "vectors") **start at index zero *NOT* one**; it's contents may be, for example, 5 but it will occupy index locations of 0,1,2,3,4....

```
[1][2][3][4][5]   <- Five items
 0  1  2  3  4    <- Their respective locations in the array
```

Same goes for visualizing characters in strings.....(technically the location in memory contains ASCII value-- look into that for fun ;) )

```
['c']['a']['t']   <- Three items
  0    1    2     <- Their index location in the array
```

I suggest Kochan's C Programming book; great for starting out!!!